# Проблема при обновлении данных в ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql, c++-cli, ado.net, update

Пытаюсь выполнить SQL запрос, при выполнении метода Fill, почему-то выбивает ошибку:

> "An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: В операции должен использоваться обновляемый запрос."

Вроде, как сам запрос обновляемый.
В чем может быть проблема?

Код на С++/CLI:

```c
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:/Users/Maks/Desktop/Project4(1)/Executor3.mdb");
OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;

command.CommandText = "UPDATE Project SET Executor_ID = " +
 "(SELECT Executor_ID FROM Executor WHERE Executor_Name LIKE " +
 "\"" + Name_CB.Text + "\"" + " AND Executor_Surname LIKE " +
 "\"" + Surname_CB.Text + "\"" + " AND Executor_Patronymic LIKE " + "\""
 + Patronymic_CB.Text + "\"" + ")" + " WHERE Project_ID=" + dataGridView_DB.CurrentRow.Index;
try
{
    connection.Open();
    adap.SelectCommand = command;
    MessageBox.Show("SQL-запрос: \n\n" + command.CommandText + "\n\nбыл выполнен успешно",
    "Запись успешно добaвлена", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
}
catch (OleDbException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + command.CommandText, "Произошла ошибка при добавлении данных", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}

adap.Fill(this.dbDataSet.Project);
dataGridView_DB.Update();
dataGridView_DB.Refresh();
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, вместо `adap.Fill` нужно использовать метод `adap.Update`.

Comment: у вас `SelectCommand` начинается со слова `UPDATE `. Не надо так

Comment: @Сергей А как надо?       ...

Comment: попробуйте вместо `SelectCommand` у адаптера поставить `UpdateCommand`